# GAE Objectify changing schema of embedded class

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

I am new to google app engine, and am finding a few issues with it.

One of these relates to changing the schema of an embedded class:

I have an entity `Exam` As follows:

```
@Entity public class Exam{
    @Id public Long id;
    ...
    public List<PairingPopulationSet> pairing_population_data = new ArrayList<PairingPopulationSet>();
}
```

`PairingPopulationSet` has changed from:

```
@Embed public class PairingPopulationSet {
    public Long examiner_id;
    public String examiner_name;
    public Integer percentage;
}
```

to

```
@Embed public class PairingPopulationSet {
    public Integer paper;
    public Long examiner_1_id;
    public String examiner_1_name;
    public Long examiner_2_id;
    public String examiner_2_name;
    public Integer percentage;
}
```

When I view the data store in the backend, I only see values `percentage`, and columns for `examiner_name` and `examiner_id` (the fields that no longer exist).

Is there a cache somewhere that needs to be updated? I have tried erasing the entire database, performing a clean build and then re-running, however the problem persists, where does GAE pull in its schemas from?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

GAE just shows you what is in the datastore, there is no cache or schema that I'm aware of.  Where are you viewing it?  You should use the view data page at:
https://appengine.google.com/datastore/explorer?&app_id=[project_id]

If that still shows the old fields even after you have recreated all the data then I would suggest that you might still be running the old version of your app.

Answer (score 0):

Read this section of the Objectify docs on migrating schemas:

https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/SchemaMigration

Changing the schema of your code does not change the data in the datastore. You must load + save each record to actually make any changes.

Comment: I was referring to the columns of new data - i.e. I create a new exam, and it sets old values (values that are never referred to in code) turns out the issue is resolved by building, deploying, running in netbeans (which fails) then running from the terminal. Very strange, if I omit the run from netbeans, I dont see the latest version.